# Chrome extension on an extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, monkeypatching

Is it possible, even in a hacky way, to make a chrome extension for an already existing extension? Or to monkey patch an existing extension?

I wish to make some simple usability changes to a non-open source chrome extension.

Comment: Perhaps chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls

Comment: `#extensions-on-chrome-urls` flag [allows](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/extensions/common/user_script.cc&sq=package:chromium&l=66&rcl=1447259195) `chrome://` urls but not `chrome-extension://` urls (there's a `canExecuteScriptEverywhere` parameter but it applies only to built-in Chrome stuff as seen in `PermissionsData::CanExecuteScriptEverywhere` function). I've added the `debugger` method to the answer which apparently is the only "kinda usable" method (the persistent notification banner makes it unusable).

Comment: Author of Surfingkeys has his own chromium [build](https://brookhong.github.io/2021/04/18/brook-build-of-chromium.html) to enable Surfingkeys on extension pages, I hope someone could find the patch and share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome extensions can't access the internal pages of other extensions which have `chrome-extension://` address (toolbar popup, page action popup, options page, background page), nor access the content scripts of other extensions.

The only case where it's possible to influence another extension (implying it's not expecting an [external connection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) from another extension) is when that other extension depends on DOM events and messages and this is the extent of it.

There's a questionable method though: using the [debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger) it's possible to execute code in the context of another extension, change its variables and so on. However a big notification will be displayed on every page in the browser:

[image]

Comment: I understand why this is disabled in Chrome designed to be as foolproof as possible, but I really can't find any reasoning behind disabling it in base Chromium. Unless there's some reasonable way around this today?

Answer (score 0):

[Get the source code and hack it](https://www.howtogeek.com/198964/how-to-view-the-source-code-of-a-chrome-extension/)

Once you have made your changes, all you have to do it enable developer mode in chrome://extensions and load up your hacky extension!