# Get background page of a different extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a personal chrome extension that always runs in development mode. I need it to communicate with a public extension (execute one of its function to be more specific).

Is there any way to get background page of the other extension so I can do this?

I also tried modifying source code of the other extension manually but then chrome show it as corrupted and ask me to reinstall it

Comment: See [Chrome extension on an extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33659482) Personally, I just make a local modified copy and load it as an unpacked extension manually updating it a few times a year. Unfortunately it requires [patching chrome.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287907/how-to-hack-chrome-dll-to-get-rid-of-the-disable-developer-mode-extensions-pop/30361260).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks! I am already using that patch. I already have two development mode extension. I guess one more won't make a difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, no.

You cannot inject scripts into `chrome-extension://` origin of a different extension, and attaching a debugger there (without whitelisted, private APIs) [is going to be tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054482/chrome-debugger-api-attach-extension-error) (custom launch flags), if at all possible. Note that there's a [feature request to allow that](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=458697).

As suggested by wOxxOm, your best bet is to create a personal copy of the other extension (if at all possible); perhaps adding hooks for [External Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) or merging your code in.